# Increment finite theorem / mean value theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f: I \longrightarrow Y$ be a continuous mapping of the closed interval $I =[0,1 ] \subset \mathbb{R}$ into a normed space $Y$ and $g: I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a continuous real-valued function on $I$. Show that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable in the open interval $]0, 1[$ and the relation $\mid \mid f^{\prime} (t) \mid \mid \leq g^{\prime}(t) $ holds at points of this interval, then the inequality $\mid  f(1) - f(0)\mid \leq g(1) - g(0)$ also holds.

How to solve this problem, for now i have the following:

Applying the finite increment theorem, I get:

$$\mid f(1) - f(0) \mid =  \mid f(c)\mid  \leq \sup \{  \mid\mid f'(t)\mid \mid  : t \in ]0,1[ \}    \mid 1 - 0 \mid \leq \sup \{   g'(t) :  t \in ]0,1[ \}\mid 1 - 0 \mid  $$

I don't know how to continue from this

Answer (score 1):

Using integrals in Bochner sense we have $\|f(1)-f(0)\|=\|\int_0^{1} f'(t)dt\|\leq \int_0^{1} \|f'(t)\|dt\leq \int_0^{1} \|g(t)\|dt=g(1)-g(0)$.

Ref. for Bochner integration: Vector measures by Diestel and Uhl.